# How do I customize the icons used in nerd-icons package

Tags: dired, customize, icons

I'm new to emacs and installed the nerd-icons.el package along with the package
nerd-icons dired. The problem is I don't like the icons set as default.
Even though i've read the nerd-icons GitHub page, it isn't clear to me what to do.
Given the link below how do I customize the nerd-icons used?

`https://github.com/rainstormstudio/nerd-icons.el`

Here is a copy of my init file

```lisp
      (use-package nerd-icons
          :custom
          ;; The Nerd Font you want to use in GUI
          ;; "Symbols Nerd Font Mono" is the default and is recommended
          ;; but you can use any other Nerd Font if you want
          (nerd-icons-font-family "Symbols Nerd Font Mono"))
        
         Use nerdicons in buffer switcher
         (use-package nerd-icons-ibuffer
          :ensure t
          :hook (ibuffer-mode . nerd-icons-ibuffer-mode))
        
        
        ;; Adds icon for  dired
        (use-package nerd-icons-dired
          :hook
          (dired-mode . nerd-icons-dired-mode))
        
        (insert (nerd-icons-devicon "nf-dev-git")) ; git-file icon
        (insert (nerd-icons-devicon "nf-dev-git_branch")) ; git-branch icon
        (insert (nerd-icons-devicon "nf-dev-git_commit")) ; git-commit icon
        (insert (nerd-icons-devicon "nf-dev-git_compare")) ; git-compare icon
        (insert (nerd-icons-devicon "nf-dev-git_merge")) ; git-merge icon
        (insert (nerd-icons-devicon "nf-dev-git_pull_request")); pull-request icon
```

EDIT:

I've posted the issue on GitHub as suggested in a comment: https://github.com/rainstormstudio/nerd-icons.el/issues/68

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue at the GitHub site: they are much more likely to be able to answer your question.

Comment: I incorporated the information from your "answer" into your question. If and when you get a satisfactory answer on your issue, *then* you might want to provide an answer here as well, explaining what to do. In the meantime, I agree with @Drew: your "answer" is no such thing, so you should delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given to me based on the GitHub Issue posted above

All I needed to do to customize the nerd-icons was to add an icon alist based on the context of its use. That being for extensions, directories, or modes, which map to the provided functions nerd-icons-extension-icon-alist, nerd-icons-dir-icon-alist and nerd-icons-mode-icon-alist, etc.

The example below:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'nerd-icons-extension-icon-alist
             '("epub" nerd-icons-faicon "nf-fa-book" :face nerd-icons-green))
```